# Blank Multipart email

Tags: php, email, yahoo, multipart

I'm using PHP to send out a multipart/mixed message (plain text, html and attachments). However, whilst it works for most accounts, Yahoo, GMail and Sky seem to show blank emails. Where as everything else seems to display the email. ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!

My headers are

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"mixed-" . $random_hash . "-mixed\"\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
```

And the content is;

```
--mixed-7df05b31-mixed  

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alt-7df05b31-alt"  

--alt-7df05b31-alt 

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 

            Hello how are you? I am just checking the mailing function.

            Hopefully this will work!

            Cheers.

--alt-7df05b31-alt 

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 

<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">

<div> 


            Hello how are you? I am just <b>checking</b> the mailing function.<br><br>


            Hopefully this will work!<br><br>


            Cheers.</div></div>

--alt-7df05b31-alt--

--mixed-7df05b31-mixed 

Content-Type: text/plain; name="abc.txt"  
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.txt"   
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SEVMTE8gSlVTVCBURVNUSU5HIC4uLiA=

--mixed-7df05b31-mixed--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't build your own MIME messages. use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) to do it for you.

Comment: because you're obviously doing something wrong. Had your email been constructed properly, it would show up in gmail/yahoo without trouble - I have yet to see PHPMailer cause a malformed message in all of my projects, regardless of where it's being read.

Comment: Though there's some value in learning to do it raw. I was wondering what's wrong with your code above?

Comment: I have also found RMail to be a very capable and easy to use multipart email library.

Comment: "Don't do it" is rarely a valid answer with coding. There will almost always be situations that require it (such as in this case, if you aren't able to incorporate external libraries for some reason). A more proper answer would be, "I would suggest avoiding this because of X reason, but if you need to, here's how..."

Answer (score 2):

It may be an artifact from pasting, but try removing the blank space at the end of each boundary. (Highlight the text and you'll notice the boundaries have an extra space, but the closing boundaries-- do not)

Answer (score 2):

Please verify whether your code is look like the following because the following code is working fine for me.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $msg."\r\n\r\n";    
$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type:application/html; name=\"".$filename."\" \r\n"; // use different content types here
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."--";
```